# GCP Import image stall at "Making disk bootable on Google Compute Engine"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, google-cloud-build

Iam trying to export a windows server 2012r2 from hyper-V to GCP.

But stall at  "Making disk bootable on Google Compute Engine"

Here is the full detail:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud beta compute images import vm000001v3 --source-file="gs://bucket2-lnc012/vm0000001v3.vhd" --no-guest-environment --os=windows-2012r2  --network=poc-local --subnet=poc-dc --guest-os-features=UEFI_COMPATIBLE  --timeout 720m



Copying [gs://bucket2-lnc/vm1v3.vhd] to [gs://lnc-test-and-oa--daisy-bkt-asia-southeast2/tmpimage/4364b524-
7f0a-40cf-972a-a286a39ce196-vm1v3.vhd]...done.
WARNING: Importing image. This may take up to 2 hours.
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/lnc-test-and-oa-/builds/c4515c24-def5-4b7f-9d7c-f880d1fdfa5e].
Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/c4515c24-def5-4b7f-9d7c-f880d1fdfa5e?project=7125205159].
starting build "c4515c24-def5-4b7f-9d7c-f880d1fdfa5e"
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T03:52:25Z Inspecting the image file...
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T03:53:49Z Creating Google Compute Engine disk from gs://lnc-test-and-oa--daisy-bkt-asia-southeast2/tmpimage/4364b524-7f0a-40cf-972a-a286a39ce196-vm1v3.vhd
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T04:19:47Z Finished creating Google Compute Engine disk
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T04:19:47Z Inspecting disk for OS and bootloader
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T04:21:15Z Disk inspection error=failed to inspect zones/asia-southeast2-a/disks/disk-3xxpg: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "run-inspection-inspect-disk-jt3py": "Failed:"
[import-image]: 2022-08-18T04:21:34Z Making disk bootable on Google Compute Engine
```

anything need to check ?

i've been check with pre-check tools: ALL PASSED

Additional from build log:

```
[translate.translate-image.wait-for-bootstrap]: 2022-08-18T04:25:04Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-bootstrap-translate-translate-image-gv576": SuccessMatch found "Translate bootstrap complete."
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:04Z Step "wait-for-bootstrap" (WaitForInstancesSignal) successfully finished.
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:04Z Running step "delete-bootstrap" (DeleteResources)
[translate.translate-image.delete-bootstrap]: 2022-08-18T04:25:04Z DeleteResources: Deleting instance "inst-bootstrap".
[translate.translate-image.delete-bootstrap]: 2022-08-18T04:25:23Z DeleteResources: Deleting disk "disk-bootstrap".
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:24Z Step "delete-bootstrap" (DeleteResources) successfully finished.
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:24Z Running step "translate" (CreateInstances)
[translate.translate-image.translate]: 2022-08-18T04:25:24Z CreateInstances: Creating instance "inst-translate-translate-translate-image-gv576".
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:34Z Step "translate" (CreateInstances) successfully finished.
[translate.translate-image.translate]: 2022-08-18T04:25:34Z CreateInstances: Streaming instance "inst-translate-translate-translate-image-gv576" serial port 1 output to https://storage.cloud.google.com/ln-int-apps-and-oa-drc-daisy-bkt-asia-southeast2/gce-image-import-2022-08-18T03:52:20Z-3xxpg/daisy-translate-20220818-04:21:34-gv576/logs/inst-translate-translate-translate-image-gv576-serial-port1.log
[translate.translate-image]: 2022-08-18T04:25:34Z Running step "wait-for-translate" (WaitForInstancesSignal)
[translate.translate-image.wait-for-translate]: 2022-08-18T04:25:34Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Waiting for instance "inst-translate-translate-translate-image-gv576" to stop.
[translate.translate-image.wait-for-translate]: 2022-08-18T04:25:34Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-translate-translate-translate-image-gv576": watching serial port 1, SuccessMatch: "Translate complete", FailureMatch: ["TranslateFailed:" "Failed to download GCS path"] (this is not an error), StatusMatch: "Translate:".
```

Comment: Your import failed. ***Disk inspection error=failed to inspect zones/asia-southeast2-a/disks/disk-3xxpg: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "run-inspection-inspect-disk-jt3py": "Failed:"***

Comment: any idea how to fix that ?